# Loss returns nan in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan, loss-function

I am training an autoencoder whose input is a matrix P in [0,1] using the following loss function:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
# Define loss and optimizer, minimize the squared error
with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
     L = -tf.reduce_sum(self.p*tf.math.log(self.p_pred+1e-10) + 0.55*(1 - self.p)*tf.math.log(1-self.p_pred+1e-10), axis = 1)
     self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(L)
self.optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
```

In main.py, I run session like this:

```
_, l, y_pred, y = sess.run([model.optimizer, model.loss, model.y_pred, model.y], feed_dict=...)
```

But the loss returns nan at different epoch whenever I'm training. The activation function is `sigmoid` and `learning_rate = 0.01`. The number of epoch is 20. I'm trying to save **p** and **p_pred** when the loss is nan, then I run  the same loss function in google colab, the result is not nan! I don't understand.

Any ideas for what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The loss function you're using is BCELoss which gives "NaN" when the value inside log is less than or equal to 0. Sometimes, your term inside the log might go <=0 and sometimes, it might not. That's why you might not be getting NaN in colab.

Try adding sigmoid in the loss function (like sigmoid(self.p_pred) instead of self.p_pred. This will ensure the term is in (0,1) range.

Else, try increasing the epsilon value (1e-10 in your code. Increase that value to 1e-5  may be)

Comment: I've already added sigmoid.  self.p_pred is the final result after sigmoid activation.

Comment: You can also try reducing your Learning rate ( may be to 0.001). There's no exact solution for loss = NaN problem. Generally people avoid it using different kind of methods. Most common methods are the ones that I have mentioned.  Sometimes, Normalisation also helps.

Comment: I have tried reducing learning rate but it's not solve the problem. I will try normalization, thank you.